# How to get the five highest values from a list in Excel

Tags: excel

In my sheet I have a Column1 with text and a Column2 with random numbers.
[image: Sheet1]

I would like to get a Column3 with the five "highest texts" for example:
[image: Sheet2]

I know I can get the text if I make an Index/Match looking for the number, but I'm lost at the sorting part.

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665435/returning-multiple-adjacent-cell-results-from-an-min-array-which-may-include-mul/34667355#34667355).  It finds the smallest but it will help you design to find the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in cell C1 and drag down:

`=LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),IF(LARGE($B$1:$B$10-(ROW($B$1:$B$10)/9^9),ROWS($A$1:A1))=$B$1:$B$10-(ROW($B$1:$B$10)/9^9),$A$1:$A$10))`

This needs to be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a 'helper column' to get the top 5 numbers with the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) then use [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) on column A, returning the appropriate row number with [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) and [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to offset duplicates.

[image: aggregate_top_five]

Comment: Geez, that must have posted before I had the image of a coffee cup in my eye.

Answer (score 1):

additional variant to already posted:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(LARGE(B:B,ROW(A1)),B:B,0))
```

test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is:  What if there is not a clean break between 5th and 5th place?  For example what if `f` was also a 6?  This would then be tied for with the others how does one descriminate?

The following will bring out only the 1st through the 5th but allow for ties that might push the actual number past 5 due to ties.

Put the following in C2:

```
 =IF(OR(ROW(1:1)<=5,COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$10,ROW(1:1)),$B$1:$B$10,0)))>0),INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$B$10=LARGE($B$1:$B$10,ROW(1:1)))*(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$1:$A$10)=0),),0)),"")
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy it down ten rows(in the picture the formula is copied down ten rows).

[image]

Now we change `f` to be `6` so it is tied for fifth:

[image]

And it gets added to the list.

You could just limit the output to five rows.  But then it would be excel deciding what is the top five.  If this is what you want than any of the other answers will work.